# Is it possible to restrict sending e-mails to virtual users only?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, ubuntu-14.04

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and using postfix. I want to block outgoing e-mail from unix users and only allow from authenticated virtual users (that I can manage via a back-office).

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: How are the virtual users separated from the unix users? How are the virtual users authenticated?

Comment: Virtual users are simply entries in a database, passwords are encrypted with `doveadm`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Postfix may have the required controls in the authentication module.  The configuration area appears to be relay_domains, where you will need to require authentication.

Try switching to Exim4 which is packaged for Ubuntu. It should be as simple as modifying the standard recipient ACL not to accept unauthenticated submissions from local addresses.  There should be a few `accept` rules early in the ACL that you will want to change to `warn` rules.  The messages will then continue to the rule which prevents relaying to external addresses.

```
  accept
    hosts = :
    control = dkim_disable_verify

  accept
    hosts = +relay_from_hosts
    control = submission/sender_retain
    control = dkim_disable_verify
```

Alternatively you could add a domains statement to the `accept` rules like this:

```
!domains = +local_domains : +relay_to_domains
```

The existing authenticated user rules will allow any authenticated user virtual or local.  Control which users can authenticate appropriately.

The [Exim Specification](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/index.html) is well written.  You should review it, or at least the ACL sections.

Comment: I am using Postfix